# Reason for shortened lifespan

Tags: scripture, karma, astrology

If lifespan reflected in birth chart  is predetermined due to prarabdha karma as can it be shortened due to any reason like accumulated  bad kriyanama karma of this life or faster exhaustion of prarabhda due to good deeds?
Any possibility of Divine Mother intervening and decreasing the lifespan?
If so, why would she do it?